# Get all recipients from email To header in PHP (ZF is a bonus)

Tags: php, parsing, email, zend-framework, header

Is there a way to parse the recipients of an email with the Zend Framework?

I'm asking, because email TO headers can contain something like this:

```
To: foo@bar.de, "Lastname, Firstname" <foo@bar.com>
```

So I can't just split on the comma. I didn't find a way to do this with the Zend Framework Mail class.

How do you do this? And is there a way to easily do this with the Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

- [`str_getcsv` — Parse a CSV string into an array](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

#### Example

```
print_r(
    str_getcsv(
        substr('To: foo@bar.de, "Lastname, Firstname" <foo@bar.com>', 3)
    )
);
```

#### Output ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qt8Ypr))

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo@bar.de
    [1] => Lastname, Firstname <foo@bar.com>
)
```

As for `Zend_Mail`, what does `ZendMail::getRecipients()` return? Or what are you using?

Comment: Zend_Mail::getRecipients() works with emails you are writing, not with the ones you are reading from a remote mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

It seems ZF doesn't have that parser. This ticket is related, but no update since Jan 2010: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3820

You can use imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist() with imap extension. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-adrlist.php

Or PEAR has a method to parse. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-rfc822.parseaddresslist.php

Answer (score 0):

depends on how the other adresses are seperated, it is possible that you can split on "\n" and then split that up further

Comment: The header does not contain a \n that separates the recipients, so this is not really a solution. Sorry.

Comment: im not exactly sure what you want to get from this string. I thought you have multiple adresses and you want to split them up. So if there is no newline, it would be good if you post a case where at least 2 adresses are listed.